# Where to find a flow in the org

Tags: visual-workflow

Using VS Code I downloaded all of the flows from the org using sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Flow.

In VS I searched for the flow Kimble Scheduling Task Event and was able to find it in the code that I downloaded (Kimble_Scheduling_Task_Event.flow-meta.xml). In VS I can tell that the flow was downloaded to the /force-app/main/default/flows. In VS looking in the org I cannot see the files, the cursor just keeps spinning. But looking in the org in Setup->Flows I cannot see the flow Kimble Scheduling Task Event. I also checked in Setup->Flows->Flow Trigger Explorer and couldn't see anything there.

Where can I go to find this flow on the org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That flow is probably a process builder...

Process builders are also categorised as flows in metadata, behind the scenes salesforce stores process builders as flow xmls...

Comment: Thanks. Found it in process builder!

Comment: N.B. `Flow` metadata type can also be other things - Login Flows, Orchestrator, Surveys, ...